# javascript function cannot be called if placed in .js

Tags: javascript, html

I m using nebeans 12.2 for maven project.  When i use following function in script tag i.e.

```
function keyPressCheck (kp, cv, isN) {
     return false;
}
```

it works fine as required but when i create a .js file in the same directory where .xhtml are placed, this function does not work.

script use is

```
<script src="functions.js"></script>
```

HTML portion is as follows

```
<p:inputText id="inp2" value="#{bean.Ctrl}" onkeypress="return keyPressCheck(event.which, this.value, #{BGPR.isNumber});"/>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: yes, i just updated the question

Comment: Have you check in the browser console is there any error

Comment: could you show more of your html

Comment: Please show where you are using the function.

Comment: does other code in the js file work? Try an alert("connected") to see

Comment: Check the path of your javascript file, is it in the same folder of your html file?

Comment: everything works f9 when placed in xhtml but when placed in .js file nothings works, i hv tested alert too which worked in .xhtml but not in .js. i hv copied the .js file in the same directory

Comment: @NasirAbbas where did you import your js file? Is it before the other markup? Is it in head or in body?

Comment: i tried in header and body too, but didn't work

Comment: In a maven project it seems highly unlikely that the path you're trying to load the file from will work. Please check the network tab of your browser's developer tools. I'm 99% sure it will tell you a `404 File not found` error for your Javascript file.

Comment: @connexo thanx a lot, i just found that if no path is given then path from the root is considered not the page's path is used. Any how, thanx for ur excellent guess and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@connexo thanx a lot, i just found that if no path is given then path from the root is considered not the page's path is used. Any how, thanx for ur excellent guess and help.

i was missing the file path of .js file.